# How can I ignore the padding of the parent class to display a subclass in full width

Tags: css

This html code contains a div container named `parent`, which has a div container `child` in it.

I want to display the class `child` in full width, so that the red box from the code snippet has a red color instead of the currently blue color on the left and right.

Of course it would be possible to set `left: -15px;` and `right:-15px;` in the CSS to archieve this, but in my case the box sizes and paddings vary.

The best way would be to ignore the padding of my `parent` class. But is this possible? Or can you recommend my another tip?

```css
.parent {
  background: blue;
  padding: 15px;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Hello World. May you help me?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you mentioned that the children paddings may vary, I suppose the parent's will be just the same, so you can always use negative margins to achieve full widths.

```css
.parent {
  background: blue;
  padding: 15px;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.second{
  padding: 15px 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Hello World. May you help me?
  </div>
  
  <div class="child second">
    Of course I would.
  </div>
</div>
```